# track open Oracle connections on the client-side

Tags: c#, database, oracle, connection

Im refactoring a program (C#) which succesfully opens many connections to an oracle-database. I have some read-rights for this db but I won't get any admin rights. I know for sure this programm opens more connections to this db than it closes but im clueless how to track them. I read that on admin-db-side you can use "V$SESSION" but because of my limited rights this isn't possible. So first off all, how can I check the number of connections this program opens and where to find them exactly? And is there a guaranteed way to close those connections?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot get direct SELECT privilges on V$SESSION (or through a role, a view or even a specific stored procedure), I don't think it is possible to get this information from Oracle.

If you refactor application code you could instead factor database connection and database disconnection in specific routines and implement your own counters in these routines.

Comment: I read from some people that I should close the connection with``` // Close and Dispose OracleConnection object con.Close(); con.Dispose(); ``` while others say I need oraConn.Dispose();         oraConn.Close();         OracleConnection.ClearPool(oraConn);  but I can't tell which one I really need. I'm also not sure how to find my own connections properly. I found that I should use con.state but there is only con.GetState

Comment: Sorry but I cannot help on C# side.

Answer (score 0):

Your DBA should create a small role with select privilege over V$_SESSION. I can't imagine why he wouldn't do that. One thing is granting you the SELECT CATALOG ROLE or the SELECT ANY DICTIONARY system privilege ( which I would, nonetheless ). When I was DBA I always had a small role for developers/analysts with the necessary privileges for them to do their support job.

Anyway, as alternative you can do is get the benefits of using SYS_CONTEXT. I would suggest to create a control logging table in your database/schema and using a procedure to collect the data of the program. This way you don't need any "so called" admin privilege

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE my_table ( c1 username, c2 session_id, c3 program, c4 timestamp default systimestamp );

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE MY_PROCEDURE 
   IS 
    V_USER VARCHAR2(130);
    V_SID  NUMBER;
    V_PROGRAM VARCHAR2(400);
    BEGIN
     SELECT
       UPPER(SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER')),
       SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'SID') ,
       UPPER(SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','MODULE'))
  INTO
  v_user,
  v_sid,
  v_program
  FROM DUAL;
  
  -- Insert the data from sys_context in your control table 

  insert into my_table values ( v_user , v_sid, v_program, systimestamp );
  commit;

  end;
  /
```

Now you only need to call this procedure in your c# program. Using this method you don't need any admin privilege, however you need to create these elements in your database.

Comment: as I said, I only have read rights. Im not allowed to create a table there nor can I get any rights for vsession, already tried it :(

Comment: It is very complicated then. I have no idea how can you that in c#. Sometimes you need to fight to overcome some constraints that don't make any sense. If your program is opening so many connections, either you have the tools to analyse it, or your DBA will have to do it for you.